# why "boost.thread" call "intrusive_ptr_add_ref" manually?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-thread

In boost.thread's start function, the source code is something like that:

```
bool thread::start_thread_noexcept()
{
    uintptr_t const new_thread = _beginthreadex(
            0, 
            0, 
            &thread_start_function,     
            thread_info.get(),          
            CREATE_SUSPENDED,           
            &thread_info->id);          

    if (!new_thread)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // why call this line?
    intrusive_ptr_add_ref(thread_info.get());

    thread_info->thread_handle = (detail::win32::handle)(new_thread);
    ResumeThread(thread_info->thread_handle);
    return true;
}
```

thread_info is a intrusive smart pointer which points to the thread information data, before calling the intrusive_ptr_add_ref, the count is already 1, I don't know why call the intrusive_ptr_add_ref mannually here. I think Intrusive smart pointer's job should be calling the intrusive_ptr_add_ref and intrusive_ptr_release automatically.

I've tried to step through the source code but didn't find any clue.

Can anyone tell me
1. why call intrusive_ptr_add_ref manually here?
2. In what condition when using the intrusive_ptr, I should call intrusive_ptr_add_ref manually?

Thanks, Sincerely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why call intrusive_ptr_add_ref manually here?

To represent the sharing of ownership of the pointer.

[`_beginthreadex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb.aspx) was passed `thread_info.get()` as a parameter. This parameter will be passed to `thread_start_function` when the thread starts. And this function expects the pointer to remain valid until that happens.

Now, `_beginthreadex` is a simple function. It's not a variadic template that can take arbitrary parameters or anything. It takes exactly and only a naked pointer, and passes exactly that to the start function.

It is very possible for the person creating the `boost::thread` to call `thread::detach` *before* `thread_start_function` ever gets called. And if that happened, then the `thread_info` intrusive pointer would be destroyed, thus causing the destruction of its contained object.

And that leaves `_beginthreadex` with a destroyed pointer. That's bad.

What `_beginthreadex` needs to do is claim ownership of the intrusvie pointer. But since the API doesn't take a `boost::intrusive_ptr`, how do you do that?

By bumping the reference count. The reference count increase is how `_beginthreadex` claims ownership of the object.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your answer is so valuable and reveals everything!